# rails: param.require(:model) ActionController::ParameterMissing OR Empty

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

My goal is to create a new Reminder record with hardcoded values:

In the following structure:

Reminder `belongs_to :deck`

Deck `has_one :reminder, dependent: :destroy`

In deck controller I get to the view like this :

```
def repitition_alerts
    @deck = Deck.find(params[:id])
    @reminder = Reminder.new
end
```

On that page I want to create a new Reminder with a link_to:

```
<%= link_to "make alerts", deck_reminders_path(@deck, @reminder,  {:action => :create}, next_alert: 'soon', interval: false), :method => :post %>
```

I am getting the following error in the browser:
`ActionController::ParameterMissing in RemindersController#create`

From terminal output:

```
ActionController::ParameterMissing (param is missing or the value is empty: reminder):
  app/controllers/reminders_controller.rb:34:in `reminder_params'
  app/controllers/reminders_controller.rb:19:in `create'
```

In the reminders_controller.rb I have:

```
def reminder_params
    params.require(:reminder).permit(:deck_id, :interval, :next_alert, :alerts)
end
```

If I understand it correctly. Rails don't see the @reminder passed into it? But it's in the page. I can put this on the same page `<%= @reminder %>` and I see `#<Reminder:0x007fc012fa00a8>` rendered out on the page. So the object itself exists.

(Rails 4.2)[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the params for `reminder` nested under `:reminder`. Switch your `link_to` to this:

```
<%= link_to "make alerts", deck_reminders_path(
      @deck, 
      @reminder,  
      {:action => :create}, 
      reminder: {
        next_alert: 'soon', 
        interval: false
      }
    ), :method => :post %>
```